# Atomic SELECT and UPDATE

Tags: php, oracle, oracle10g

If my data looks like this:

```
ID STATUS     DATE_ADDED
== ========== ==========
 1 Processing 2011-04-01
 2 New        2011-04-02 
 3 New        2011-04-03
 4 Processing 2011-04-03
 5 Done       2011-04-06
 6 New        2011-04-06
 7 New        2011-04-14
 8 Done       2011-04-14
 ...
```

... what's the recommended way to pick the 10 oldest records with status "New" and set their status to "Processing" while ensuring that any other concurrent process cannot do the same with the same records?

It's a web application running on PHP/5.2.6 under Windows Server 2003 that connects to a remote Oracle 10g server through ODBC (Oracle's driver, not Microsoft's).

Comment: Why is it important that only *your* process update the 10 oldest "new" rows to "processing"?

Comment: Using Advanced Queueing (AQ) instead of rolling your own?

Comment: @Catcall - Because records need to be processed once and only once.

Comment: @Shannon Severance - I've had a look at Advanced Queueing in Oracle documentation. Correct me if I'm wrong but it looks like an impressive technology that cannot be learnt from scratch in a few hours; I wish I had the time :(

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario: I don't know enough to answer, what I do know is a requirement like this came across my desk, I would spend some serious time exploring AQ before rolling my own. However, I'm not in your shoes, you know about AQ, investigated and decided against it. My comment was only meant as a prompt to take a look and you already have.

Comment: Take a look at atomic `UPDATE ... RETURNING` feature from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029277/oracle-sql-how-to-read-and-increment-a-field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is hard to do in Oracle 10g.  In 11g, the `SELECT FOR UPDATE ... SKIP LOCKED` syntax makes it easy.

A simple `UPDATE` statement will serialize.  As will a `SELECT FOR UPDATE`.  Sure, two competing processes won't ever get the same rows; the problem is that they will at best serialize, and at worst, they can deadlock.

The recommended way would be to use Oracle Advanced Queueing (or the queuing implementation of your choice) to enqueue to the IDs to be processed, and allow the queueing implementation to manage the contention for values.

--

The SQL will work, but will fail with an ORA-00054 if a second user runs it for the same offsets while someone has that range locked.  That can be mitigated by wrapping the select in a loop, catching the ORA-00054 error and using that to increment the offsets.

```
select * from my_table
 where rowid in 
       (select row_id 
          from (select rowid as row_id, rownum as rn 
                  from mytable where some_condition 
                 order by deterministic_sort_order)
         where rn between :low_rn and :hi_rn
       )
 for update nowait;
```

The sort expression needs to be deterministic (simply, include the primary key as the end of the sort expression) to prevent collisions.

Comment: I've been playing with `SELECT FOR UPDATE` and it looks promising but I'm having problems combining it with the `ROWNUMBER<10` clause that I'm using to limit the size of the result set: if I use a subquery to filter out the top 10, Oracle won't accept FOR UPDATE. I'm seriously considering to lock *all* the `New`records (in my particular case it may not be a big deal).

Comment: @Adam Musch: Wish I could upvote again for the updated answer in addition to the upvote on the original answer.

Comment: You don't want ", rownum as rn" in the innermost select. Change "where rn between :low_rn and :hi_rn" to "where rownum <= :hi_rn". Rownum is assigned during the initial phase of the query, before the "order by," i.e., before the sort is done.

Comment: Another way to fix this query is to change "rownum as rn" to "row_number() over (partition by 1 order by some_sort_order)".

Comment: @redcayuga - it works - I checked it on 10.2.0.4.  Rownum is flowing out of the innermost query, assigned after the order by, and isn't being filtered on until afterward.  Further, you don't want to use `row_number () over` when `rownum` will do.

Comment: @Adam Musch - I've written some code with a query that's basically the one you propose and it works like a charm. By detecting `ORA-00054`, I can make concurrent processes either wait or pick another rowset. (For whatever the reason, the production server is neither enforcing locks nor triggering errors, but it works fine in my local XE copy; that's another story I'll need to fix next week.)

Comment: @Adam Musch: I'm sure this works on the data you tested it on but it won't work correctly on all datasets and database configurations. For example, if Oracle uses an index to access the table and that index is in the same order as the "order by" it will work correctly because Oracle doesn't need to do an explicit sort. Try this query "select rownum, o.* from user_objects o order by o.timestamp desc". The rownums came out in almost random order when I ran it on one of my schemas. But they could come out in order.

Comment: @redcayuga - if you're looking to emulate queueing without actually using queuing, why aren't you hitting the data using an index in sorted order in the first place?  You're not going to want to sort an n-row table every time - and multiple times to boot, if other sessions already have the first m rows locked anyway!  Also, how many different objects have the same timestamp in user_objects?  Try ordering by `timestamp, object_id` to get a deterministic sort.

Comment: @Adam Musch: My point is that I only need one example to prove a solution is incorrect and that a minor change can make the query correct. Furthermore, depending on the existance of an index for query correctness is a bad practice, period. Indexes are for performance. It's bad enough an index is required to enforce primary keys. It's bad enough that we need an index to enforce primary keys. But to use an index in a non obvious way so that a query works as you want is just asking for trouble.

Comment: @redcayuga - if you're looking to get the top 10 rows, the problem statement to me implies that the rows can be sorted deterministically.  If your sort expression ever has more than 10 duplicates, you can't guarantee that you won't have competing sessions attempting to lock the same rows.  The query isn't broken - your sort expression is insufficient.  I just tested it again with a snapshot of user_objects where there are 49 rows with the most current timestamp.  It breaks if object_id isn't part of the sort, but works if it is, and there's no indexes in place.  So, again, it works.

Comment: @Adam Musch: when I order by "timestamp, object_id" the first ten rows do not contain rownums 1 to 10 (in aany order.) I get: 2, 3, 5, 12, 13 1, 4, 7, 8, 9. These rows represnt the 10 earliest timestamps but the rows with rownums of 12 and 13 will get excluded by the "where rn between" clause in favor of rownums 6 and 10 which have later timestamps. Remember, I only need one example to prove the query is incorrect. You can provide 1000 dataset examples and they still won't prove the query is correct if one incorrect example exists.

Comment: @redcayuga - build the testcase as a question with the release of Oracle you're on, and I'll review it.  Your counter-case, from what I can tell, misses the fact that there's not one, but two levels of nesting going on in the referenced answer, where the innermost nested query sorts (and thus determines rownum, aliased externally as rn) and the outermost nested query filters based on the earlier (and therefore determined) rn column.  Further, your counter-case can't SELECT FOR UPDATE or use ROWIDs, because **it is against a view**.

Comment: This will get the same ten rows every time - try it and see:  `select * from (select rownum as rn, o.* from user_objects o order by o.timestamp, o.object_id) where rn between 1 and 10 order by rn`

Answer (score 2):

Use a transaction to do that. Using the isolation level "[serializable](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/settransaction_statement.htm)" for the transaction will prevent any other process to access/modify the rows while your transaction is working on them.

> If a serializable transaction tries to execute a SQL data manipulation statement that modifies any table already modified by an uncommitted transaction, the statement fails.

You may want to use:

```
set transaction isolation level serializable;
```

Comment: "SERIALIZABLE: If a serializable transaction tries to execute a SQL data manipulation statement that modifies any table already modified by an uncommitted transaction, the statement fails." The OP didn't want to know how to make his *own* statement fail.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I was not aware of the fact that transactions can prevent access to affected rows, I'll look into it. But I guess I need to do the `UPDATE` first and then find a way to retrieve the precise rows I've updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new table and put one row in it. Your program can then lock the row with an update or select for update before proceding to the original table. This will work if all programs use the same procedure to mark the table "Processing."

```
create table Lock_Table (
  app_catagory  varchar2(20) primary key,
  usage_ts      timestamp(6)
 );
```

Insert one row: `insert into Lock_Table (app_category) values 'APP1'` and commit. This is a one time insert.

Then to lock out other sessions: `update Lock_Table set usage_ts = current_timestamp where app_category = 'CAT1'`

You don't need the usage_ts column, you can use a `select for update`.

As long as you do the above update before the "select the 10 oldest" query you'll guarantee your result. I recommend putting everything in one procedure (or one procedure in a package) to make it easy for application programmers to "do the right thing."

Comment: Sorry but I did not understand. Maybe you can give a name to the new table and columns so I figure out...

Comment: I added a "create table" and instructions.

Comment: Thanks for the update, now I get it. I actually had a similar `poor man queue` idea that involved a long random string and a `OWNER_PROCESS_RANDOM_STRING` column :)

Comment: In fact, you can even block on the row without committing it. If two concurrent sessions both insert a row with the same primary key value, the "slower" session will still block via an `enq: TX - row lock contention` event.

Answer (score 1):

A heavy handed way to solve this is to lock the table so no other session can update it:

`lock your_table in exclusive mode`

Unfortunately, other sessions won't be able to insert new rows until the locks are released so this can really reduce the concurrancy of the application.

Comment: I've just upvoted your answer. Most other answers provide excellent reliable and fine grained mechanisms to do the task. I've even written and tested a full working prototype in my development box that works like a charm. But nothing works when I upload it to the production server, no matter how nicely that same code runs in my local PC... except the gross `LOCK TABLE table_name IN EXCLUSIVE MODE`. While I obviously need to do further debugging, it's fair to recognise so :)

Answer (score -1):

Just for note

also, **Optimistic Locking** strategy can be applied to slove this issue

Comment: That's a bad idea in this particular case. The OP should really lock pessimistically and make sure that all other processes are locked out from acquiring the "mutex" on the `'New'` rows